# How to separate data from one column result into multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is sample data and expected results:

Table 1 :

```
out_number AMPS   VA  Feed
1          0.00   0   A
2          0.10   0   A
3          0.15   0   A
4          0.30   0   B
5          0.40   0   B
6          0.80   0   B
```

Query Results:

```
out_number AMPS   VA  Feed  out_number AMPS   VA  Feed
1          0.00   0   A     4          0.30   0   B
2          0.10   0   A     5          0.40   0   B
3          0.15   0   A     6          0.80   0   B
```

My current query:

```
select d1.*, d2.out_number, d2.AMPS,d2.VA,d2.Feed
from #tbl1 d1 ,
     #tbl1 d2
where d1.Feed = 'A' and d2.Feed = 'B'
```

But getting below result

[image]

Comment: No relations between the A and B rows?

Comment: What's the expected result if there are another A row, e.g (7, 0.85, 1, A)?

Comment: (7,0.85,1,A,null,null,null,null)

Comment: what if there are more than 6 rows ?how it will appear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, create two sub sets `Feed = 'A'` and `Feed = 'B'` and join them with unique column (i used a `row_number()` here).

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT row_number() over(order by AMPS) row_no, * 
            FROM @table1 t1 where t1.Feed = 'A' ) T1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT row_number() over(order by AMPS) row_no, * 
                FROM @table1 t2 where t2.Feed = 'B' ) T2
        ON T1.row_no = T2.row_no
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , you save my time

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an inner join the same table

```
 select d1.*, d2.out_number, d2.AMPS,d2.VA,d2.Feed 
 from #tbl1 d1
 inner join #tbl1 d2  on d1.out_number = d.out_number
 where d1.Feed = 'A' and d2.Feed = 'B'
```